# intent to launch gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I want to launch android's native gallery through an intent, I want user to pick one media from gallery either an image or video but both should be listed there. My problem is now i can launch gallery for either an image or video. I searched a lot but not found any solution which perfectly works. Right now i am doing:

```
Intent mediaChooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
mediaChooser.setType("video/*, images/*");
context.startActivityForResult(mediaChooser, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

here i tried above but not work always and also i tried for single type i.e, :

```
mediaChooser.setType("video/*");
          OR
mediaChooser.setType("image/*");
```

Can any one tell me how to get both type of media files to be appeared in Gallery?

Answer (score 0):

Following code works fine for me on **android 2.2**.Try..
**Vedio**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("video/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

**Image**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

**For Both**
Try..

```
final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
galleryIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: I have tried in 4.0.4 and 4.1.1 in both the version it fails.

Comment: I see,then it may be unsupported in 4 version,but supported in 2.2..:)